# Find a module from VBA editor in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, function, vba, module

I am updating an Excel Spreadsheet from Office XP .xls to Excel 2010 .xlsm.  When I did this, some of the function names were renamed or are not able to be accessed any more.

These are hundreds of functions on hundreds of module pages in my VBA editor.  Is there some way to find the function I am looking for without opening each module and searching through it?  It seems to me that find only works inside of each module page.

I still have the working xls and if I could just, for example, control click the function name and it would open up the module that contained that function, I would know where it was.  Is something like that possible?  Or is there a function finder?

Thanks!

Comment: `Find` works either inside a procedure, module, or project (or selected text). So it will find the procudure, even in another module

Answer (score 0):

(Everything below is related to the VB Editor)

- Right-click on the function name, then chose "Definition" in the context menu.
- For error checking, go to VBE menu "Debug" → "Compile <module-name>".
- For structured overview of all the available methods, properties, events, objects, types, press [F2].

(For UDFs found in formulas of worksheets)

- Keep the spreadsheet and the VBE open;
- Copy the name of the UDF from the formula;
- Paste it in the Object Browser [F2] in the search box; double click on the found UDF will open the containing module.

Unfortunately, I don't know a more straightforward way, but is better than manual search I think. :-)

Comment: Right-clicking in the VB editor will give me the choice of "Definition", but I need to find it from the formula in my spreadsheet.  When I right click there I get cut, copy, paste options, format cells, pick from drop-down list, and collapse formula bar.

Comment: @EngineerWithJava54321 Oh, you're using the functions as UDFs in the spreadsheet? Maybe you should mention that explicitly in the question, just to be more clear. Let me think...